# What is the name for printed 2FA codes on a wallet card?

Tags: multi-factor, terminology

What is the correct name for the 2FA device that is [printed codes on a wallet card](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/general/bingoHelp.php)?

These codes are sequentially numbered from 001 to 224.  The log in screen displays 2 numbers in that range and the user is to map those numbers to codes which become what is effectively a second password.

Comment: like this? https://www.passwordcard.org/en or https://www.savernova.com/en/solutions/secure-password-card/tutorial

Comment: @schroeder Those products that you linked do not use codes or numbers displayed by the website that you are trying to log in to.

Comment: where did you run across such a scheme?

Comment: like this? https://web.deepnetsecurity.com/authenticators/one-time-password/grid-card/

Comment: @schroeder Interactive Brokers has a battery operated wallet card as well as a printed codes wallet card.  The obvious difference is that the battery operated card requires a password to enable operation.  Other than that, I don't know if there is any difference.

Comment: IB uses 2 terms for the card (bingo and security code card), and while NIST describes the broad category of approach for the card, the actual name for the card is not defined by a standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NIST uses general term look-up secret authenticator.

> "A look-up secret authenticator is a physical or electronic record
> that stores a set of secrets shared between the claimant and the CSP.
> The claimant uses the authenticator to look up the appropriate
> secret(s) needed to respond to a prompt from the verifier. For
> example, the verifier may ask a claimant to provide a specific subset
> of the numeric or character strings printed on a card in table
> format."

Source: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf chapter 5.1.2

Comment: One small note: NIST describes "Look up secret" as a broad category of authenticators, and not specifically the "wallet card". The wallet card is a type of look up secret authenticators.

Answer (score 2):

There is no established term because the cards are proprietary.

I have seen several terms:

- grid card
- authentication card
- bingo card
- password card
- security code card